# Shopify bulk file upload to assets

Tags: ruby, content-management-system, shopify

I wanted to upload my previous theme on shopify, which is a 401mb zip file. But the shopify only allows 50mb max upload. So I unzipped my theme, then moved away some files from their asset folder, making the theme lighter. Then rezipped it, and uploaded it.

Now, I have successfully uploaded the theme. I need to upload all 300+ images that were moved from their asset files back to the uploaded theme. How do I do a bulk upload on the assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no actual bulk upload option for shopify.

That said you can use `themekit` create a local instance of your theme and add the files in the asset folder and the themekit will start uploading each file separately in a queue.

You can refer to https://shopify.github.io/themekit/

In order for  this to work you need:

1. themekit added to your local machine
2. create a `private app` in your store ( from the Apps screen there is
   private app option at the bottom `Working with a developer on your
   shop? Manage private apps` )
3. create a `config.yml` file in our local machine ( following this
   guide
   https://shopify.github.io/themekit/#configure-an-existing-theme )
4. download your theme `theme download`
5. start watching it `theme watch`
6. paste your image files in the asset folder

Answer (score 2):

You can use Shopify's [Assets API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/asset) to upload them, using a custom app or a tool like [Themekit](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the product import and upload images as product images. Just make the product invisible and something convenient for the url for the assets you want to use. I was able to upload 50+ animated gifs this way using a google sheet and importing a product that I named "asset".